# VB importing of DLL functions with build type conditionals

Tags: vb.net, string, dll, constants

So I'm trying to import a function from a library I'm developing. I have "libraryD.dll" built for debugging and "library.dll" for release. Unfortunately, that means that I have to do this:

```
#If Debug
Declare Function someFunction Lib "library.dll" Alias "someFunc" () As Integer
#Else
Declare Function someFunction Lib "libraryD.dll" Alias "someFunc" () As Integer
#EndIf
```

Now this would be fine but for ALL 40 functions this would make things very ugly to look at (and a tad bit unfriendly).I would like to do something more like this:

```
#If Debug
#Const dllName = "libraryD.dll"
#Else
#Const dllName = "library.dll"
#EndIf
Declare Function someFunction Lib dllName Alias "someFunc" () As Integer
```

Is there ANY way to do this in VB? :-(

TIA!

Comment: Is your library that you're importing from a .Net assembly?

Comment: Nope, just a C++ library of functions that I've created from scratch.

Comment: I don't know if it is the "right way" to do this, but in the past, I just make a .NET wrapper that has everything I need.  You'll want to do this if you need to marshal anything anyway.  In this wrapper, you can include logic for switching to the other assembly's functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply do one thing...

```
    Dim dllName as string
    #If Debug
    dllName = "libraryD.dll"
    #Else
    dllName = "library.dll"

    Declare Function someFunction Lib dllName Alias "someFunc" () As Integer
```

This will certainly solve your problem... 
Happy coding... :)

Comment: This will not work because the DLL name needs to be a constant string.

Comment: Ok, So change dllName to const dllName.

Comment: Did you test it?  I believe I tried that and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DLLImport attribute:

```
#If Debug
 Const dllName = "libraryD.dll"
#Else
 Const dllName = "library.dll"
#EndIf

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(dllName)> Private Shared Function somefunction() As Integer
    End Function
```